# Why does mod_rewrite redirect to /index.php/index.php/index.php etc

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, xampp

I want every subdomain to act as a folder, so basicly:

```
projects.dev -> /
test.projects.dev -> /test
amazing-project.projects.dev -> /amazing-project
```

And I have this code in my Virtualhost file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName projects.dev
  DocumentRoot "D:/xampp/htdocs/projects"
  ServerAlias *.projects.dev
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.projects\.dev
  RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ "D:/xampp/htdocs/projects/%1/$1" [L,R=301]
</VirtualHost>
```

However when i go to "designs.projects.dev" it gets redirected to 
"designs.projects.dev/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/" (the /index.php continues for a while).

**Does anyone know why this happens?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName projects.dev
  ServerAlias *.projects.dev

  DocumentRoot "D:/xampp/htdocs/projects"

  RewriteEngine on

  RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.)([^.]+)\.projects\.dev$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ /%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: The server doesn't start when I use VirtualDocumentRoot

Comment: What is your Apache version?

Comment: Apache 2.4.27 (Win 32)

Comment: Oh `VirtualDocumentRoot` needs 2.4. let me edit it accordingly